# I was writing simple code in JQuery in brackets but '$' shows undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried everything mentioned in this forum, Tried newer versions of jQuery Checked every spelling spent two hours to find out the problem but got no result.

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe you use jqeury before jquery loaded

Comment: I thought that too , i deleted the file reloaded jquery and recoded but the issue remained. I literally spent last two hours for just these four lines of code

Comment: Down voted because of image like @Alexander said, and also, if you updated the code, then please also update the details in your question to reflect.

Comment: Where do you have your javascript? Is  it in head or below script tags?

Comment: Are you using Wordpress? In that case try to replace `$` with `jQuery`. Also, your line with `h1` has an error and Should be `'h1'`

Comment: It's in the body of html document

Comment: @Chri.s I'm using bracket

Comment: @sahirAK bracket - is that the bootstrap template? anyways, have you tried replacing `$` with `jQuery` to see if it works? The `$` is turned off when jQuery noConflict is turned on. Anyways, since it's not because of wordpress I guess that it's probably because the script isn't loaded in the <head> as the others point out.

Comment: @Chri.s thanks i will try that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened because jQuery is not properly installed to be sure before coding run the code below. If it gives you alert message "jQuery is installed correctly" you are good to go.

```
<head>

<title>JQuery</title>

    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(typeof jQuery=="undefined"){

            alert("jQuery is not installed ")

        }else {

            alert("jQuery is installed correctly")
        }

   </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jQuery **before** using it. Move the `<script>` tags that defined after footer into [`<head>`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp) before script that you try to run.

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('h1').click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#ff0000')
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Click Me</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: @sahirAK, see the snippet. Try to run it.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @sahirAK, remove semicolon, see the snippet above.

Answer (score 1):

Move Jquery to the `<head>`. If not, you could try

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('h1').click(function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#ff0000')
    })
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This will make sure your Global jQuery variable is bound to the "$".

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('h1').click(function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#ff0000')
    })
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

You could also load the script externally. I often find this to work better with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your script file/code just below the `jQuery` library file link

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('h1').click(function() {
      jQuery(this).css('background-color', '#ff0000')
    })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: @sahirAK just replace `$` with `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your file is REALLY loaded
2. Add a new file, and only import jQuery from googleapi. Then, go to your browser's developer tools (F12), abd in console try to execure '$'. If it's not throwing an error, go to 4. If it is throwing an error, go to 3.
3. Check your internet connection to googleapi: Open the jQuery file in your browser, and check if it is loaded properly.
4. Try add 'refer' to your script tag like this:
5. If error still occurs, feel free to comment below.